# Failed to instantiate module ngCookies

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

For all who see the same error message:

I uses bower to install angular-cookies. First I used

```
bower install angular-cookie
```

I injected ngCookie to my module, but go the error message "Failed to instantiate module ngCookies"

Answer (score 7):

Use `angular-cookies` instead of `angular-cookie`. Note the 's'.

[`angular-cookie`](https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie) (with no 's') is a package, but not the correct one. `ng-cookie` depends on [`angular-cookies`](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies) (in its plural form).

```
bower install angular-cookies
```